# Drawing Image pixel by pixel in android in a very fast manner

Tags: android, performance, drawing, pixel

I need to draw an image pixel by pixel to do some effects, but I nned to do that in a very effecient way.  I heared that I can use c++ to make this task faster in android...Would you please help me how to do this in a very effecient manner.

Comment: This is a broad question to ask here

Comment: `pixel by pixel` and `in a very effecient way` don't go together well. You better use **ColorMatrices** if your effects are sepia toning, grayscaling, color shifting, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe,you can try [OpenCv](http://opencv.org/).
OpenCV is released under a BSD license and hence it’s free for both academic and commercial use. It has C++, C, Python and Java interfaces and supports Windows, Linux, Mac OS, iOS and Android. OpenCV was designed for computational efficiency and with a strong focus on real-time applications. Written in optimized C/C++, the library can take advantage of multi-core processing.